# Centos / almalinux how to rebuild glibc and gcc (DNF broken) and "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"

Tags: yum, gcc, glibc, dnf

My dnf / yum is broken

```
yum update -y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

errors about GLIBC not found...

when I try to compile glibc OR gcc I get

```
"no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"
```

how can I recompile gcc and/or glibc without a working dnf

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed ?

Comment: There is a chicken and egg problem, you don't have GCC to compile GCC neither you have working yum/dnf to install it.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. Don't concentrate on the compile issue. Step back and ask `how do I get this system back into a working state`? Do you have either a working `rpm` on your system or both `cpio` and `rpm2cpio`? If so you can install packages if you can get them onto your system. Can you ssh into the system or can you plug in something like a USB drive?

Comment: Without a working `dnf` there’s no point in messing around with compilers.  Fix that first.